# How to debug asset prompiling syntax errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

I'm trying to push to Heroku after some Frontend touching, but I have several errors when precompiling (I think syntax errors).

The thing is, I get the line number of the precompiled assets, not the original ones, so I don't know how to debug it.!

```
  ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 20575, col: 0, pos: 641944)
       Error
       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:10623)
       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:10842)
       at croak (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:19067)
       at token_error (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:19204)
       at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:19292)
       at /tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:27484
       at /tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:29977
       at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:30735)
       at /tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:30827
       at /tmp/execjs20141029-3052-g386xfjs:2357:31270
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can still compile your assets locally in this situation and then go to the line in question in you compiled application.js file.

So

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

(you need to have a local "production" database to run this `bundle exec rake db:create:all`)

then open `public/assets/application-some_md5_hash.js` in your editor

In your case you would go to line `20575` and look for a crazy `<` somewhere

Make sure you clean up and remove your `public/assets` folder so you don't accidentally check it into version control

I'm pretty sure this will also work in the situation that you have funky CSS by going to the application-md5stuff.css

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you but in my Gemfile i had the wrong version of ruby installed running

```
  bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

it told me what version I had, updating it worked for me.